# Deploy rasa model using MITIE on rasa-x which got error

Tags: rasa, rasa-x

I have trained a model and works fine with "rasa shell". Then I have deployed rasa-x on kubernetes, and try to upload the model. Here is the problem, my pipline has used MITIE:

```
pipeline:
  - name: "MitieNLP"
    model: "total_word_feature_extractor_zh.dat"
```

but rasa-x seems cannot find the "total_word_feature_extractor_zh.dat", and got error:

```
Error loading MITIE model file: total_word_feature_extractor_zh.dat
Unable to open total_word_feature_extractor_zh.dat for reading.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

How did you deploy Rasa X to Kubernetes? You need to make sure your `rasa` service has access to the language model at `./total_word_feature_extractor_zh.dat`.

Comment: you are right, by default the rasa/rasa docker do not have total_word_feature_extractor_zh.dat, I need to create a new docker extends rasa/rasa and put the dat file in.